# Concatenating specific words together in an array list

Tags: java, arrays

I have a problem, suppose I have a text file like so:

Name Surname, number, number ..... number\n
Name Middle  Surname, number, number......number\n
Name, number, number ..... number\n

I wanted to keep the "names + surname" or "names +middle +surname" in each line into one array list index.
For Example, I want "Name Surname" of the first line in one index of an array list.

I did try using a string variable and adding the two elements together in a loop. But as you see the names aren't really of any specific type.
How would I do it? I would really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose you have a `String` variable called `line` which holds a given line. In this case:

```
String namePart = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(","));
String dataPart = line.substring(line.IndexOf(",") + 1);
```

This should help you get started.

The first row assigns the part of line left to the first comma to `namePart`. The second row assigns the part of line right to the first comma to `dataPart`. Of course, you will need to split `dataPart` using comma as separator and build an array or something like that and add the relevant information into a new entry of your item set.

Comment: That's the one - I somehow missed that the names weren't comma delimited.

Comment: the dataPart should be `line.substring(line.IndexOf(",")+1)` otherwise it includes the delimiter itself

Comment: Hey, yeah so I tried doing it this was and it worked! thanks ! :D

Comment: @NeilDas you are welcome. If this answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: @LajosArpad: have done that. I also did it in my own method. Its given below. Check it out, you can think of it as another way.

Comment: @NeilDas yes, that's an alternative you can work with.

Answer (score 1):

So I did what was mentioned in the above answers. But I also did a something different.

Code:

```
void readScore() {
    int nextToken;
    int numberOfTokens = 0;
    String nameOfStudent = "";
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    StreamTokenizer myToken;

    // create a buffered stream to read from the file
    try {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(inputFileName)));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(
                "File Not Found. Please add file in the proper directory or give the proper file path and execute");
        System.exit(1); // exit if file not found
    }
    myToken = new StreamTokenizer(bufferedReader);
    myToken.eolIsSignificant(true);

    try {
        nextToken = myToken.nextToken();
        while (nextToken != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
            if (nextToken == StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER) {
                marks.add(myToken.nval);
                numberOfTokens++;
            }
            if (nextToken == StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD) {

                nameOfStudent += myToken.sval + " ";
            }
            if (nextToken == StreamTokenizer.TT_EOL) {
                students.add(nameOfStudent);
                nameOfStudent = "";
            }
            nextToken = myToken.nextToken();
```

It works! let me know if this is efficient. But it definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to split the line :

```
String[] parts = line.split(",");
```

This gives you an array with all parts.  `parts[0]` holds the name, and all the numbers following in subsequant indexes.